# Spring JUnit Test - JSONPath for Integer not Matching

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have the following assertion in my JUnit tests for my Spring based Rest Controller

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..terminationPoint.downstreamSpeedKbps", is(Integer.valueOf(500))));
```

this assertion is being made against the following payload:

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "terminationPoint":{  
            "downstreamSpeedKbps":500
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and I'm getting the following error when the assertion runs:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$..terminationPoint.downstreamSpeedKbps"
Expected: is <500> but: was <[500]>
```

any idea where those square brackets are coming from or what do they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$..` will perform a deep scan and return an array of all the values is your json.
Use specific index instead:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.result[0].terminationPoint.downstreamSpeedKbps", 
                    is(Integer.valueOf(500))));
```

[Here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com) you play with the jsonpath and check for the results

Comment: The first solution works, the second returns the following error: `Expected: is [<500>] but: was <[500]>`

Comment: @SamanthaCatania You are right. Removed the second solution. As long as you have the json array as a result, the better way is to use index of the result

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is: expression `$..` gives you an `Array` back.. you can also recognize it from the error message `[]`, you can do this:

`$..terminationPoint.downstreamSpeedKbps[0]`

Comment: This returns an empty array and results in the following error: `Expected: is <500> but: was <[]>`